# Git - find name of file at commit

Tags: git

Say I create a new repository and add the file foo.txt with some text and commit (hash A), and then I rename the file bar.txt and commit (hash B). I then want to see what the name of the file was in A. I am trying the following command

```
git diff -M --name-status A..B -- bar.txt
```

where A and B are the two hashes. This is just returning "A bar.txt" - how can I get it to indicate that the file was renamed from foo.txt?

*(Note: I understand that git doesn't track renames and uses a similarity index, but similarity in this case should be 100%. Also note that this is a simplified example - for my actual use case I only want to assume that A is an ancestor of B, (**EDIT:** and cannot assume that the files are 100% similar.))*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the file rename [**Edit**: from `git diff` that is; see [eftshift0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67536997/1256452) for a method if you're sure of a 100% match] without having Git do a full comparison of the two commits.  That is:

```
git diff -M --name-status A B -- bar.txt
```

won't work.  In theory:

```
git diff -M --name-status A B -- foo.txt bar.txt
```

could work, but I don't think it does.  (You can try it to see if it does work, but it won't solve your actual problem since you're trying to *find* the name `foo.txt` in the real problem case.)

The reason for this is that, as you note, Git doesn't actually track the renames.  Instead, it just *discovers* the rename.  To do that it has to enumerate all the left-side (`A` commit) files, and all the right-side (`B` commit) files.  It then finds that, gosh, on the left, there's a removed `foo.txt` and on the right there's an added `bar.txt`.  Maybe, just perhaps, those might be "the same" file, whatever that means.  At this point Git compares the two files—along with other added and/or removed files—to find out how similar they are and decides on "sameness" by picking those that have the best matches, above whatever the similarity threshold is.<sup>1</sup>

When you limit the diff to just one file with `-- bar.txt`, Git *doesn't look at* the entire left and right sides.  It just trims them down to the one file and then does the comparison.  That comparison finds "missing from left, exists on right" and thus Git classifies the file as `A`dded.

The easy(ish) way to find the rename you are looking for is:

```
git diff -M --name-status --diff-filter=R A B
```

after which you must scan through the output (if doing this programmatically from a capable language, consider adding `-z` to the diff options) to find one in which the rename is "to desired name".

Note: I've used `A B` exclusively here instead of `A..B` as they have the same meaning to `git diff` and `A B` is one character shorter.  The Git folks are trying to encourage people to move away from the two-dot syntax.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git does a first pass to find 100% similar files and remove them from the possible-match-up matrix, because the similarity-index computation is expensive.

Comment: Very informative! It's a bit sad though that it needs to compute every rename for every file, only to throw away most of the work.

Comment: I bet it doesn't happen for every file. trees that have the same IDs won't be looked at if their paths in the revisions are the same.

Comment: @eftshift0: yes, but that's not really relevant here since the result would be the same either way. Git is only looking for files that were apparently-deleted (exist on left, missing on right) and apparently-created (missing on left, exist on right). If the algorithm did not short-cut identical tree hashes, it would just find identical files on both sides, leaving the rename-detection matrix empty of anything from those subtrees.

Comment: Also worth noting: if you add the `-C --find-copies-harder` flag, Git has to consult every source file (every left side file), regardless of whether it matches any right-side file, to see if the left-side file might be the source of a copy that resulted in a new right-side file. That's why the documentation mentions that duplicate `-C`, or `--find-copies-harder`, is extra-intensive.

Answer (score 4):

If the file hasn't changed content, you can use its id to find out. This is not elegant, but it works:

```
$ git ls-tree HEAD -- build.sbt
100644 blob a154be0bf501840c2bbecf8a570cffb8541f6758    build.sbt
$ git ls-tree -r HEAD~ | grep a154be0bf501840c2bbecf8a570cffb8541f6758
100644 blob a154be0bf501840c2bbecf8a570cffb8541f6758    build.sbt
```

Comment: Ah this is interesting and does work for this example, but for my use case I don't have this guarantee. Updated the question to reflect that, but upvoting.

Comment: Then check @torek's response. To me, they are the ultimate word on a git question.